# Null bind variable in MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I have a `SELECT` statement as below:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE column1=COALESCE(:col,column1)
```

When I run this in MYSQL and leave the `:col` bind variable empty I get an error. So basically, if `:col` is null the query fetches all the rows else the query fetches only the rows matching the value in `:col`.

I am running in the MYSQL window.

> The error is #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near ':col1,column1) LIMIT 0, 25' at line 1.

I know this is possible in Oracle. Since I am new to MYSQL, hence the question.

Comment: Read this: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/user-variables.html

Comment: @forpas thanks for replying. The content in the link shared by you does not seem relevant to what I am asking. I basically want to know if it is possible to leave the bind variable blank when running a SELECT statement in the MYSQL window.

Comment: @forpas, read the content again. Spot on!!! Issue resolved.

Answer (score 1):

All I had to do was initialize the variable before the query as

```
set @col1 ='';
```

I ran the query again and it returned the desired result.

Comment: @rajendra singh Why can I not answer my question?